# Using v-slot and v-chip does not allow editing of chips

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to programmatically change the color of chips inside of a v-combobox if there is an error for that element.

I was just using v-combobox with chips before. This allowed editing of the chips by double clicking. Here's a codepen that allows editing similar to what I was using that allows editing. 
https://codepen.io/hassaan97/pen/ZEYWveE

Since I wanted to change the color of individual chips I am using v-slot with v-chip components. Once I do this however I can no longer edit the items when I click on them. Here's a similar example with the same problem. https://codepen.io/hassaan97/pen/KKwzZNY

Here's my code-

```
             <v-combobox
              v-model="emails"
              multiple
              :search-input.sync="syncEmail"
              :chips="true"
              :deletable-chips="true"
              :clearable="true"
              :error-messages="errorMessage"
              @click:close="remove(data.item)"
              :background-color="white"
            >

              <template v-slot:selection="data">
                <v-chip close :color="getColor(data.item)" @click:close="remove(data.item)">
                  <strong>{{ data.item }}</strong>&nbsp;
                </v-chip>
              </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selection slot exposes a `select` function:

```html
<template v-slot:selection="data">
  <v-chip @click="data.select">
```

https://codepen.io/kaelwd/pen/ZEYWvMQ

[Here's what the default chip does](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/432c4db29a521323e0c2b40a6a164cc99c0fbcb3/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.ts#L344-L364)
And [everything available in the slot](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/432c4db29a521323e0c2b40a6a164cc99c0fbcb3/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.ts#L520-L533)